# Runtime error when trying to delete char*

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, char, delete-operator

I have this piece of code:

```
cout<<"Enter first name (maximum "<<MAX_LENGTH<<" letters):";
cin>>name;
cin.ignore();
name[MAX_LENGTH] = '\0';
fName = new char [strlen(name)];
strcpy(fName, name);
delete [] fName;
```

But as soon as it hits the `delete [] fName` line, I get a runtime error.
I figured from previous posts that this happens because i change the pointer to the allocated memory when doing `strcpy(fName, name);`. but I have no idea what to do to avoid it.

Comment: use `name[MAX_LENGTH-1]= '\0';`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the runtime error happens here `strcpy(fName, name);`

Answer (score 1):

```
fName = new char [strlen(name)];
strcpy(fName, name);
delete [] fName;
```

You allocated an array of length `strlen(name)`, but then copy `strlen(name)+1` characters. That is because `strlen()` returns a value that excludes the null-terminator. But `strcpy` copies the null-terminator.

This means that the call to `strcpy` writes beyond the end of the buffer and after that the program's behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If `name` is declared like `char name[MAX_LENGTH]`, then maximum index can be `MAX_LENGTH-1`, since array has *zero based indexing*. Using

```
name[MAX_LENGTH] = '\0';
```

accesses memory beyond the limit. use

```
name[MAX_LENGTH-1]= '\0';
```

Also your `name` should have `MAX_LENGTH-1` character.

```
cout<<"Enter first name (maximum "<<MAX_LENGTH-1<<" letters):";
```

And `fname` must be as large as `name` to be copied in, and **Must Be** allocated using `new` if you want to de-allocate it using `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fName = new char [strlen(name)];
strcpy(fName, name);
delete [] fName;
```

The problem is strcpy need strlen(name)+1 characters (extra one for ending 0). Read about C string representation.